# Findcontrol on webform using master page returning null

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm dynamically creating a number of controls on a page and trying to subsequently refer to them, the webform has a master page and findcontrol is returning null. I *think* I've structured this in the correct way based on msdn and previous questions on this site so I'm stumped as to why it's not working

```
for (int i = 1; i <= Convert.ToInt32(TextBoxNumCols.Text); i++)
        {
            string MyFindString = "TextBoxColName" + i;
            ContentPlaceHolder MasterContent = this.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
            TextBox CurrentTextBox = MasterContent.FindControl(MyFindString) as TextBox;
            SqlString += CurrentTextBox.Text;
            SqlString += " int,";
        }
```

This fails at the first iteration. `MyFindString` populates fine and `MasterContent` finds the placeholder on the master page, but `CurrentTextBox` is always null

View source on page determines that the control exists as:

```
ContentPlaceHolder1_TextBoxColName1
```

Comment: Your `FindControl` works just fine. The problem is not in this snippet. Are you binding the TextBoxes on every page load? Not just inside an `if (!IsPostBack) { addTextBoxes(); }` statement?

Comment: Yes I think this is the problem, postback for this event is removing the controls so there is nothing to find. Is there a simple way to work with the values entered into dynamically created controls before they are lost? (I don't really need to recreate them at postback, just work with the values they contained)

Comment: No you need to recreate them, otherwise you get the above error. After you get the values you can remove them with `Placeholder1.Controls.Clear();`.